# Как проверить карта двигается или нет?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Есть картинка и в зависимости от того клиент двигает карту или нет она будет отображаться. То есть открылась карта на ней стоит прикрепленная фотка, клиент начал вести по карте без разницы в право-влево и тд, фотка становится невидимой. Перестал вести по карте - фотка снова отобразилась. Как такое сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думал сделать свой обработчик и наткнулся на статью она на Енглиш иза этого переводить лень .Если коротко то начиная с августа 2016 добавили возмомжность слушать карту ,реализующуюся следующим интерфейсом Прошу кусок кода как это сделать

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener, GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener,
        GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener,
        GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveCanceledListener,
        GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener {
```

Заимлементели и у них есть методы вот эти

```
@Override
public void onCameraIdle() {
    Log.d(TAG,"camera perestala dviqatsa");
}

@Override
public void onCameraMoveCanceled() {
    Log.d(TAG,"camera canceled");
}

@Override
public void onCameraMove() {
    Log.d(TAG,"camera dvijetsa");
}

@Override
public void onCameraMoveStarted(int i) {
    if (i == GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener.REASON_GESTURE) {
        Log.d(TAG,"camera vxod");
    } else if (i == GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener
            .REASON_API_ANIMATION) {
        Log.d(TAG,"camera reson api");
    } else if (i == GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener
            .REASON_DEVELOPER_ANIMATION) {
        Log.d(TAG,"camera developer api");
    }
}
```

Так же не забудьте указать

```
   map.setOnCameraIdleListener(this);
    map.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener(this);
    map.setOnCameraMoveListener(this);
    map.setOnCameraMoveCanceledListener(this);
```